# How can I pass common arguments to Perl modules?

Tags: perl, module

I'm not thrilled with the argument-passing architecture I'm evolving for the (many) Perl scripts that have been developed for some scripts that call various Hadoop MapReduce jobs.

There are currently 8 scripts (of the form run_something.pl) that are run from cron.  (And more on the way ... we expect anywhere from 1 to 3 more for every function we add to hadoop.)  Each of these have about 6 identical command-line parameters, and a couple command line parameters that are similar, all specified with Euclid.

The implementations are in a dozen .pm modules. Some of which are common, and others of which are unique....

Currently I'm passing the args globally to each module ...

Inside run_something.pl I have:

```
set_common_args         (%ARGV);
set_something_args      (%ARGV);
```

And inside Something.pm I have

sub set_something_args {
    (%MYARGS) =@_;
}

So then I can do

```
if ( $MYARGS{'--needs_more_beer'} ) { 
    $beer++;
}
```

I'm seeing that I'm probably going to have additional "common" files that I'll want to pass args to, so I'll have three or four set_xxx_args calls at the top of each run_something.pl, and it just doesn't seem too elegant.

On the other hand, it beats passing the whole stupid argument array down the call chain, and choosing and passing individual elements down the call chain is (a) too much work (b) error-prone (c) doesn't buy much.

In lots of ways what I'm doing is just object-oriented design without the object-oriented language trappings, and it looks uglier without said trappings, but nonetheless ...

Anyone have thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 10):

In the same vein as Pedro's answer, but upgraded to use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) and [MooseX::Getopt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Getopt), I present the SO community with... a Moose [modulino](http://www.drdobbs.com/184416165)*: a Moose module that can be included and run normally as a module, or separately as a command-line utility:

```
# this is all in one file, MyApp/Module/Foo.pm:

package MyApp::Module::Foo;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Getopt;

has [ qw(my config args here) ] => (
    is => 'ro', isa => 'Int',
);

sub run { ... }

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub run
{
    my $module = MyApp::Module::Foo->new_with_options();
    $module->run();
}

run() unless caller();
```

The module can be invoked using:

```
perl MyApp/Module/Foo.pm --my 0 --config 1 --args 2 --here 3
```

Using this pattern, you can collect command-line arguments using one module, which is `use`d by all other modules and scripts that share the same options, and use standard Moose accessor methods for retrieving those options.

*<sub>modulinos are modules that can also be run as stand-alone scripts -- a Perl design pattern by SO's own brian d foy.</sub>

Comment: Or just skip the boilerplate main, consume MooseX::Runnable, and say `mx-run MyApp::Module::Foo --args --go --here`.  No hacks required.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `import` in `Getopt::Long`. You pass arguments to your module through `use Module qw/.../` and grab those via the `import` subroutine.

```
# Override import.                                                                                                                                                                                  
sub import {
    my $pkg = shift;            # package                                                                                                                                                           
    my @syms = ();              # symbols to import                                                                                                                                                 
    my @config = ();            # configuration                                                                                                                                                     
    my $dest = \@syms;          # symbols first                                                                                                                                                     
    for ( @_ ) {
        if ( $_ eq ':config' ) {
            $dest = \@config;   # config next                                                                                                                                                       
            next;
        }
        push(@$dest, $_);       # push                                                                                                                                                              
    }
    # Hide one level and call super.                                                                                                                                                                
    local $Exporter::ExportLevel = 1;
    push(@syms, qw(&GetOptions)) if @syms; # always export GetOptions                                                                                                                               
    $pkg->SUPER::import(@syms);
    # And configure.                                                                                                                                                                                
    Configure(@config) if @config;
}
```